# Test images loaded in css background-image with Stenciljs and Jest

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

I have a component created in Stenciljs like the following:

```html
<fd-story
      image="https://img-global.cpcdn.com/recipes/1f9d5949e79d5526/751x532cq70/lomo-saltado-foto-principal.jpg"
      name="Cyzone">
</fd-story>
```

Internally, I rendered the component with the following code:

```js
/**
   * value for the url image
   */
  @Prop() image = '';

  /**
   * visit state for the image
   * default false.
   */
  @Prop() visit = false;

  /**
   * name for the label
   */
  @Prop() name = '';

  private get getClasses() {
    return this.visit ? 'story-image-visit' : 'story-image-novisit';
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div class="story-container">
        <div class={this.getClasses} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.image})` }} />
        <div class="label">
          <span>{this.name}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Whe I try to make my tests, I write:

```js
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/dist/testing';

import { Story } from '../story';

describe('fd-story', () => {
  it('should create Story atom component', () => {
    expect(new Story()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('Suite tests for story component', () => {
    it('should render the story component', async () => {
      const page = await newSpecPage({
        components: [Story],
        html: `<fd-story
        image="https://img-global.cpcdn.com/recipes/1f9d5949e79d5526/751x532cq70/lomo-saltado-foto-principal.jpg"
        name="Cyzone"
      ></fd-story>`,
      });
      expect(page.root)
        .toEqualHtml(`<fd-story image="https://img-global.cpcdn.com/recipes/1f9d5949e79d5526/751x532cq70/lomo-saltado-foto-principal.jpg" name="Cyzone">
      <mock:shadow-root>
        <div class="story-container">
          <div class="story-image-novisit" style="background-image: url(https://img-global.cpcdn.com/recipes/1f9d5949e79d5526/751x532cq70/lomo-saltado-foto-principal.jpg);"></div>
          <div class="label">
            <span>
              Cyzone
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mock:shadow-root>
    </fd-story>`);
    });
  });
});
```

And I have the following error:

[image]

I found some answers on Google, but they didn't solve the problem:

I have added the following to the package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|sass)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
    }
  }
```

But I can't solve the error.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries it this way:

```js
    page.rootInstance.image = 'https://img-global.cpcdn.com/recipes/1f9d5949e79d5526/751x532cq70/lomo-saltado-foto-principal.jpg';
    page.rootInstance.name = 'Cyzone';

    await page.waitForChanges();
    
    expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(...)
```

instead of passing parameters through element?